# getting unhandled exception type malformed url exception

Tags: java, exception

I'm pretty new to java , actually I have just started learning it
I tried to do an exercise and the exercise was to read the first five lines of a webpage
for start I wrote this code :

```
import java.io.* ;

import java.net.URL ;

class testcode {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL address = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/") ;
        InputStream is = address.openStream() ;
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is) ;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr) ;
        String line = reader.readLine() ;
    }

}
```

but when I run this piece of code through Eclipse , I get this :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
at test.testcode.main(testcode.java:10)
```

Why is this happening !?

and ofcourse when I dont put the throws Exception part at the begining I get the malformed url exception !

PS : my internet connection works just fine !

Can Somebody please help me and explain why is this happening while doing that ?
I have a pretty good c++ background so feel free to explain as deep as you can :D

Comment: I really think you should post your actual code. The code you posted works fine.

Comment: so what is the problem then !? :/
Is it Eclipse Just Actin Crazy !?

Comment: This code is working fine at my end...

Comment: @AshkanKzme The problem is that you are not showing us the real code that causes the exception to be thrown.

Comment: this is my Eclipse window :
http://upload7.ir/images/62162506249029350911.jpg

Comment: @AshkanKzme are you using any firewall/proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your program can't connect to the URL. Are u using internet behind proxy? If so, then make sure ur program is configured accordingly. One way is to use this code:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxy.mydomain.com");
System.setPropery("http.proxyPort", "8080");
```